# A new entity was found through the relationship - error

Tags: doctrine-orm

I try to establish a simple association of two tables. But I always geht the following error:

A new entity was found through the relationship 'Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Client#abos' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Abo@00000000211b173900000000cf7658ac

Here are my Models:

```
<?php
namespace Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert,
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection,
Shopware\Components\Model\ModelEntity,
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="joe_kaffee_abo_abos")
 */
class Abo extends ModelEntity
{

    public function __construct() {
        $client = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Unique identifier
     *
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Client",     inversedBy="abos", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    protected $clients;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="desc", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $desc = '';


    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name_en", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name_en = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="desc_en", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $desc_en = '';


    //getter and setters...
}
?>
```

Client Model:

```
<?php
namespace Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert,
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection,
Shopware\Components\Model\ModelEntity,
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="joe_kaffee_abo_client")
 */
class Client extends ModelEntity
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->abos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Unique identifier
     *
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Abo", mappedBy="clients", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    protected $abos = null;

    public function addAbo($abo)
    {
        $abo->addClient($this);
        $this->abos[] = $abo;
    }


    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerid", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $customerid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="customernumber", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $customernumber;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $is_active;

    //Getters and Setters
}
?>
```

The error occurs after I executed the following statements:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setCustomerid(12);
$client->setCustomernumber(12);
$client->setIs_active(true);
Shopware()->Models()->persist($client);

$abo = new Abo();       
$abo->setName("name");
$abo->setDesc("desc");
$abo->setName_en("name");
$abo->setDesc_en("desc");

$client->addAbo($abo);
//$abo->addClient($client);
//$client->addAbo($abo);

Shopware()->Models()->persist($client);
//Shopware()->Models()->persist($abo);
Shopware()->Models()->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

What this is telling you is that you need to save the Abo Entity before saving the client.

```
$abo = new Abo();       
$abo->setName("name");
$abo->setDesc("desc");
$abo->setName_en("name");
$abo->setDesc_en("desc");
Shopware()->Models()->persist($abo); //Persist the Abo before assigning it to the client

$client->addAbo($abo);
//$abo->addClient($client);
//$client->addAbo($abo);

Shopware()->Models()->persist($client);
//Shopware()->Models()->persist($abo);
Shopware()->Models()->flush();
```